# CodeFirst EF - Register model manually

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

Instead of doing:

```
 public class MyContext : DbContext
 {
      DbSet<MyModel> MyModels {get;set;}
 }
```

I just want to create one context "to rule them all", like below.

```
 public class GenericContext : DbContext
 {
      public GenericContext(param type[] modelTypes){
           //How can I do something like the following line?
           base.ModelBuilder.RegisterAll(modelTypes) //PSEUDO CODE
      }
 }
```

All the queries I make can then be made against the `Set<T>()` property of the DbContext.

Is it possible to do something like the above and create a migration script at the same time? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible since "Code First" has the ability to create the database itself but all the schema at once on the first run, meaning it should be static because it does not create tables on demand.